# Why it's a bad idea to use Scriptlets in JSP pages

Tags: jsp

Few beginners question about Scriptlets:

- I've red that using Tags is the better way, but tags are kind of complicated, making a simple date output takes 2 minutes instead of 15 seconds.
- How often do people use Scriptlets?
- And finally, if it's not a good idea to use it, then why is it even available?

Comment: Hy!  Maybe this aswer can help you about scriptlets!!
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: Thanks. What about using "include" to include other JSP files instead of using tags, is that discouraged too?

Comment: Maybe custom tags in JSP are a lot of work but you can use an easier alternative called "tag files" see docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html In addition, today we have "custom EL functions" see docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio

Comment: Here are links to above http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html    http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio